# Angular 4 - Loopback 2 "Internal Server Error" "Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: node.js, angular, loopback

I do not know why i get this error, i followed the tutorial Tour of Heroes of Angular

Code:

```
public productsURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/productos';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getProducts (): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsURL)
      .pipe(
        tap(products => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getProducts', []))
      );
  }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAQn5.png]

Comment: This is not clear at all. It means the error is in your loopback. Take  a look at your server and give us much details

Comment: Oh! Try to test API first before integration with Angular. This is your Server issue. Post your server code.

Comment: The error is not at loopback, I tried the api with a google chrome extension and it worked appropriately. I can not do gets :(

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getProducts() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:3000' + '/api/productos');
  }
}

Comment: can u please check url "http://localhost:3000/api/productos" I think its products instead of productos